# delete nested object base on key in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to remove an object of an object in react, what I'm planning to do is get the current state and assign it to a variable, alter that variable, use setState to assigned the altered variable to state. Like this

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      obj: {
        "0": {
          something: 123
        },
        "1": {
          another_thing: 'abc'
        }
      }
    }
  }

  deleteOneObj(index) {
    let newObjState = this.state.obj[index]
    delete newObjState
  }

  render() {
    return(<h1>hello<br />
      <button onClick={()=>this.deleteOneObj(1)}>
        delete one obj
      </button>
    </h1>)
  }
```

But delete newObjState doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You are not deleting the object property. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: so if I do `delete newObjState[index]` what's next?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using Object.assign, it's more readable and also creates a new reference of an object:

```
deleteOneObj(index) {
    let newObjState = Object.assign({}, this.state.obj)
    delete newObjState[index]
    this.setState({obj: newObjState}) 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
deleteOneObj(index) {
    let newObjState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.obj))
    delete newObjState[index]
    this.setState({obj: newObjState}) 
  }
```

Comment: hmm why? is there any alternative which is more descriptive?

Comment: This mutates the state, which is [bad](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/prerequisite-concepts#immutable-data-management) (assuming redux here)

Comment: @DerekAdair this doesn't mutate state. I'm JSON.stringifying the object which returns a string, all reference to the current state is lost. That is one way to deep clone an object